# How to generate an axis2 client from Service with overloaded methods

Tags: java, .net, web-services, interop, asmx

I have an old asmx service which I need to contact via a java (axis2) client.
Problem is the service has some overloaded methods and the wsdl2java tool throws a duplicate operation error.

Obviously changing the service is not an option. Is there a way around this issue?

Can a .Net client handle this? If so maybe I can write a .Net layer to serve as a proxy between my client and the service.

Are there other wsdl/java generators that might support this?

**SOLUTION:**

Since i need to use only some of the methods of the service , what i did was to download the WSDL to my local disk, then i removed the duplicated methods and generated stubs from them (with XmlBeans, ADB does not work).

Again, this solution is only good if you don't need all the methods and you can get rid of the duplications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to generate the client from the Eclipse IDE using the axis2 plugin?

All you need to have the Eclipse set with tomcat and axis2 runtime and then create a Dynamic Web project and add the WSDL to src and then generate the client.

I think it should generate the client without any issue.

Comment: I'm using the wsdl2java tool which is provided by axis2 and essentially is the same tool Eclipse uses when using the axis2 plugin (at least to my knowledge). But just to make sure I tried it and stumbled on the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Axis 1.4 does support overloaded methods, so if you can afford to have an older axis version, this might be a solution.